# SpringBoot how delete selected SQL record (thyme leaf, javascript, java, Doma2)

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to be able to delete selected SQL record.

If the button next to a record is clicked, a pop-up screen saying "Do you really want to delete it?"

And if yes is clicked,

the record FROM SQL next to the button that was clicked is deleted from the table.

I am really stuck in this, even a little help will help.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>selectToDelete</title>
</head>
<body >
    

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(session.sessionInfo.input,session.sessionInfo.input2)}">

            <td th:text="${session.session2.goodsList[i].G_name}">
            <td th:text="${session.session2.goodsList[i].G_id}">
            <td th:text="${session.session2.goodsList[i].G_price}">


<td > <button type="submit" name="deleteParam" th:value="${i}" onclick="DeleteButton1(this.value)">selectButton</button></td>

        </tr>
    </table>



<script th:inline="javascript">
function DeleteButton1(e) {
        if (confirm("Do you want to Delete?")) {

             window.open('deleteScreen', '_self' );

        }else{
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "session2" })
public class DeleteScreen {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteScreen", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String skensaku(Model model, @ModelAttribute("sessionInfo") CondTrainingForm condForm) {


        return "selectToDelete";
    }

}
```

REPOSITORY↓

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.seasar.doma.Dao;
import org.seasar.doma.Select;
import org.seasar.doma.boot.ConfigAutowireable;

import com.example.domain.CondTrainingEntity;
import com.example.model.CondTrainingForm;

@ConfigAutowireable
@Dao
public interface DbConnectRepository {

    @Select
    List<CondTrainingEntity> selectDynamic(CondTrainingForm form);
```

service↓

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DbConnectService {

    @Autowired
    private DbConnectRepository dbConnectRepository;

    public List<CondTrainingEntity> selectUser(CondTrainingForm cond) {
        return dbConnectRepository.selectDynamic(cond);
    }
```

SQL file↓

```
SELECT
 G_name, G_id,
 G_price
              FROM

              GOODS

              WHERE
    G_name LIKE /* @infix(form.G_name) */'G_name'
AND 
  G_id  LIKE /* @infix(form.G_id) */'G_id'
         
AND
  G_price LIKE /* @infix(form.G_price) */'G_price'
```

Comment: How did the records get from the database to your Thymeleaf UI page in the first place? Are you using Spring Data JPA? Do you have an annotated JPA model entity bean? A Jpa/CrudRepository?  A @Service interface and implementation class?
What elements/components do you already have?

Comment: JpaRepository/CrudRepository have a built-in deleteById() function that takes the primary key value as input.

Comment: @Emily spring-bot

Comment: @Howard007 I have added my repository, service and SQL file, This is how I got my records from the database. Do I need to study spa crud repository in order to do the delete?  I had a feeling if I could bring this "function DeleteButton1(e) " <- e value back to controller. I would know the place the record picked(selected) to delete from the list.

Comment: @Emily I think my video lecture course can help.  Here is the link, with a limited FREE coupon.  Let me know if it works, and if it helps.
https://www.udemy.com/course/intro-db-app-dev-springboot-angular/?couponCode=FF48B944C24317E4FA6A